# Laravel error Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Connection::prepareBindings() must be of the type array, string given, called in

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Code I would like to work, but getting an error:

```
$test= 'test1';
$add = DB::insert('insert into clients (name,user_id,subdomain) values (?, "3", "test")', $test);
```

Error:

```
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Connection::prepareBindings() must be of the type array, string given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php on line 454
```

This code, however works:

```
$add = DB::insert('insert into clients (name,user_id,subdomain) values ("name", "3", "test")');
```

How would I get the code in the first example to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to pass your values in as an array. It's as easy as adding the brackets around it.

```
$add = DB::insert('insert into clients (name,user_id,subdomain) values (?, "3", "test")', [$test]);
```